# VisualSVN server connection outside a network

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to setup a VisualSVN Server in Windows 7 but sudenly I can't connect to the host ( name or IP ).  When I'm in the same network as the PC installed with the program I can access the SVN only with PC name for server name and checkouting with http://external_ip/svn/RepoName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache must listen on all interfaces, you have only on LAN. Reconfigure server